# How can i add a custom font into html code

Tags: html, datetime, fonts

We are working with digital signage software that is pretty much based on HTML. I have generated a code for date and time from free time and date site, which is nice, and it has our language (serbian) supported.

However, there are a few fonts that are predefined which can we chose, none of which is pretty font. I wanted to know if its possible to add a code into it which can call a custom font which i uploaded on our personal storage. Im not that good with HTML, and seeing that this might be the best site for HTML problems on internet i thought that i might ask here

Here is the code:

```
<iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i4c0bglr/n3395/tlrs36/fn10/fs36/tct/pct/tt0/tb4" frameborder="0" width="504" height="86" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

thnx in advance

Comment: Do you have the option of creating a php file on your server, same site as the webpage which contains the iframe? Thus using the php to be a proxy and allowing Same-origin policy to give us javascript access to change the css to use a pretty font.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add custom fonts to your CSS.

It's a little bit tricky to get it right, because you need to convert your font file to 5 different file-types, and you then have to get your font-declarations just right. There are tools for this, but I haven't found one that does everything exactly right yet. [Here is one](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

If you are, as you say, not good with HTML, I would personally recommend [Google Web Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts). It's the easiest way of getting the results that you need fast.

EDIT:

Pure HTML font selection:

```
<font face="Helvetica">Text text text</font>
```

(only system fonts)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But im not using a website, im using a digital signage software, which works like a placeholder where i insert a html code. i dont have a css. is it possible to insert a line of the code or smt?

Comment: Ok. In "pure" HTML you are limited to installed fonts on the system you are running. But since you are making this application maybe you could make it install the font you need before loading the HTML view? Without CSS you use the `<font face="font-name">`-tag to set the font you want.